# Stateful Amadeus Soap Header 4 Request in Postman

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, amadeus

I am attempting to communicate throught the amadeus soap api using https://www.getpostman.com/. So I did build my Soap Header v4 Request as their documentation states, however I always end up receiving a SoapFault "11|Session|"

I am also setting the HTTP-Header *SOAPAction* to *http://webservices.amadeus.com/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A* in this case.

When I am using clients like https://github.com/amabnl/amadeus-ws-client this works, but when trying to fire the very same request using postman it does not, any ideas?

## Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:ns1="http://xml.amadeus.com/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A"
                   xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
                   xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wsswssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
                   xmlns:ns4="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3"
                   xmlns:ns5="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:MessageID>x-x-x-x-x</ns2:MessageID>
        <ns2:Action>http://webservices.amadeus.com/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A</ns2:Action>
        <ns2:To>https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/AAAAAAAAA</ns2:To>
        <oas:Security xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <oas:UsernameToken xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1">
                <oas:Username>AAAAAAAAA</oas:Username>
                <oas:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">aaaaaa==</oas:Nonce>
                <oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">aaaaa=</oas:Password>
                <oas1:Created>2018-08-28T08:46:39:293Z</oas1:Created>
            </oas:UsernameToken>
        </oas:Security>
        <ns4:Session TransactionStatusCode="Start"/>
        <ns5:AMA_SecurityHostedUser>
            <ns5:UserID POS_Type="1" PseudoCityCode="AABBBCCDDEE" AgentDutyCode="AA" RequestorType="U"/>
        </ns5:AMA_SecurityHostedUser>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <!-- actual request -->
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

## Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:awsse="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <soap:Header>
        <wsa:To>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</wsa:To>
        <wsa:From>
            <wsa:Address>https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/AAAAAAAAA</wsa:Address>
        </wsa:From>
        <wsa:Action>http://webservices.amadeus.com/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:x-x-x-x-x</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:RelatesTo RelationshipType="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/reply">yyyyyy-xxxxx</wsa:RelatesTo>
        <awsse:Session TransactionStatusCode="End">
            <awsse:SessionId>xxxxx</awsse:SessionId>
            <awsse:SequenceNumber>1</awsse:SequenceNumber>
            <awsse:SecurityToken>xxxxx</awsse:SecurityToken>
        </awsse:Session>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring> 11|Session|</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong here, I was using security information in the Soap-Header (v4) **AND** in the Body for the Security_Authenticated Request itself.

I removed any Security-Headers, this way it works just fine, so the working request looks like:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
               xmlns:ns1="http://xml.amadeus.com/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
               xmlns:ns3="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns2:MessageID>X</ns2:MessageID>
    <ns2:Action>http://webservices.amadeus.com/VLSSLQ_06_1_1A</ns2:Action>
    <ns2:To>X</ns2:To>
    <ns3:Session TransactionStatusCode="Start">
    </ns3:Session>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:Security_Authenticate>
        <ns1:userIdentifier>
            <ns1:originIdentification>
                <ns1:sourceOffice>X</ns1:sourceOffice>
            </ns1:originIdentification>
            <ns1:originatorTypeCode>x</ns1:originatorTypeCode>
            <ns1:originator>X</ns1:originator>
        </ns1:userIdentifier>
        <ns1:dutyCode>
            <ns1:dutyCodeDetails>
                <ns1:referenceQualifier>X</ns1:referenceQualifier>
                <ns1:referenceIdentifier>X</ns1:referenceIdentifier>
            </ns1:dutyCodeDetails>
        </ns1:dutyCode>
        <ns1:systemDetails>
            <ns1:organizationDetails>
                <ns1:organizationId>X</ns1:organizationId>
            </ns1:organizationDetails>
        </ns1:systemDetails>
        <ns1:passwordInfo>
            <ns1:dataLength>0</ns1:dataLength>
            <ns1:dataType>X</ns1:dataType>
            <ns1:binaryData>X</ns1:binaryData>
        </ns1:passwordInfo>
    </ns1:Security_Authenticate>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting `11|Session|` error, that means you are sending incorrect data.
Few things you need to check.

- Date time in "Zulu" timezone,because Amadeus validates the time to their time so that only 30 minutes of time difference is allowed.
- Password digest algorithm.
- Using same nonce within 30 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions though!